# Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't boot anymore after kernel update

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, boot-failure

After the kernel upgrade to 3.0.0.13.15 my system doesn't boot anymore. I have to manually shut down the system, reboot and choose the old kernel to be able to boot my system. The only thing I see is that caps and scroll lock are blinking/flashing. The system hangs on the purple grub background.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You can loggin via ctrl-alt-f1.
The `startx` command tells me nvidia module is not found.

I fixed it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd> -> `dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current`

Answer (score 0):

Use the rescue mode or go to another terminal with ctr+alt+f1 and reinstall your drivers. Usually installing new kernel will break graphics drivers really bad.